# Recognize numbers in french format inside document using regex

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have a document containing numbers in various formats, french, english, custom formats.

I wanted a regex that could catch ONLY numbers in french format.

This is a complete list of numbers I want to catch (`d` represents a digit, decimal separator is comma `,` and thousands separator is space)

```
d,d d,dd   d,ddd

dd,d   dd,dd   dd,ddd

ddd,d   ddd,dd   ddd,ddd

d ddd,d   d ddd,dd   d ddd,ddd

dd ddd,d  dd ddd,dd  dd ddd,ddd

ddd ddd,d  ddd ddd,dd  ddd ddd,ddd

d ddd ddd,d...

dd ddd ddd,d...

ddd ddd ddd,d...
```

This is the regex I have

```
(\d{1,3}\s(\d{3}\s)*\d{3}(\,\d{1,3})?|\d{1,3}\,\d{1,3})
```

catches french formats like above, so I am on the right track, but also numbers like `d,ddd.dd` (because it catches `d,ddd`) or `d,ddd,ddd` (because it catches `d,ddd` ).

What should I add to my regex ?

The VBA code I have:

```
Sub ChangeNumberFromFRformatToENformat()

Dim SectionText As String
Dim RegEx As Object, RegC As Object, RegM As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RegEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = "(\d{1,3}\s(\d{3}\s)*\d{3}(\,\d{1,3})?|\d{1,3}\,\d{1,3})"
    ' regular expression used for the macro to recognise FR formated numners
    End With

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count()

    SectionText = ActiveDocument.Sections(i).Range.Text

    If RegEx.test(SectionText) Then
        Set RegC = RegEx.Execute(SectionText)
        ' RegC regular expresion matches collection, holding french format numbers

        For Each RegM In RegC

            Call ChangeThousandAndDecimalSeparator(RegM.Value)

        Next 'For Each RegM In RegC

        Set RegC = Nothing
        Set RegM = Nothing

    End If

Next 'For i = 6 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count()

Set RegEx = Nothing

End Sub
```

The user stema, gave me a nice solution. The regex should be:

**(?<=^|\s)\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*(?:\,\d{1,3})?(?=\s|$)**

But VBA complains that the regexp has unescaped characters. I have found one here (?: \d{3}) between (?: \d{3}) which is a blank character, so I can substitute that with \s. The second one I think is here (?:,\d{1,3}) between ?: and \d, the comma character, and if I escape it will be \, .

So the regex is now (?<=^|\s)\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*(?:\,\d{1,3})?(?=\s|$) and it works fine in RegExr but my VBA code will not accept it.

NEW LINE IN POST : 
I have just discovered that VBA doesn't agree with this sequence of the regex **?<=^**

Comment: Is this really a *complete* list of numbers you want to catch? Or a representative list? If you have to specify "I think you got the picture", then sounds like the latter.

Comment: IMO, it's perfectly ligit to match `d,ddd` in a text containing `d,ddd.dd`. If you want to forbid this kind of construct, just express what is a malformed number: a wellformed shall not be followed by...

Comment: Those last two examples look like English-format numbers, but how can we know the rest of them are French?  Who's to say `100,001` is *one hundred point zero zero one* (French) and not *one hundred thousand and one* (English)?  Unless there are more clues to be found in the text, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: @ Po' Lazarus : malformed number : d,ddd.d,  d,ddd.dd  d,ddd.ddd d,ddd,ddd   help ? thank you very much for all your time, and help!

Comment: @ Alan Moore  : totally right. but how can I minimize the destruction of other numbers such as d,ddd.d,  d,ddd.dd  d,ddd.ddd  d,ddd,ddd  ? thank you for all your time and support

Comment: @ Jean-François Corbett : yes this is a complete list of the numbers I want to catch, the ONLY numbers I want to catch.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
\b\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?:,\d{1,3})?\b
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v8ic)

`\b` are word boundaries

At first (`\d{1,3}`) match 1 to 3 digits, then there can be 0 or more groups of a leading space followed by 3 digits (`(?: \d{3})*`) and at last there can be an optional fraction part (`(?:,\d{1,3})?`)

**Edit:**

if you want to avoid `1,111.1` then the `\b` anchors are not good for you. Try this:

```
(?<=^|\s)\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?:,\d{1,3})?(?=\s|$)
```

[Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v8m7)

This regex requires now a whitespace or the start of the string before and a whitespace or the end of the string after the number to match.

**Edit 2:**

Since look behinds are not supported you can change to

```
(?:^|\s)\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*(?:,\d{1,3})?(?=\s|$)
```

This changes nothing at the start of the string, but if the number starts with a leading whitespace, this is now included in the match. If the result of the match is used for something at first the leading whitespace has to be stripped (I am quite sure VBA does have a methond for that (try `trim()`)).

Comment: hello stema, i tried to match the regex against 1,111.1 and it worked. and this is a kind of number I don't wanna catch. Any new ideas ? thank you very much for your timie and support!

Comment: @ stema : I have just checked all the malformed numbers I could think of right now, and it totally worked. I shall test it on the doc and let you know. thank you very much for your time and support

Comment: @ stema : I couldn;t test it.. the VBA complains that the regexp has unescaped characters. I have found one here (?: \d{3}) between (?: \d{3}) which is a blank character, so I can substitute that with \s. The second one I think is here (?:,\d{1,3}) between ?: and \d, the comma character, and if I escape it will be \, . So the regex is now (?<=^|\s)\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*(?:\,\d{1,3})?(?=\s|$) and it works fine in RegExr but my VBA code will not accept it. Any ideas ? Thank you for all your help. Kind regards.

Comment: @RaduPuspana space and comma don't need to be escaped. But it can be that you need to double escape special characters. So try `\\s` instead of `\s` and `\\d` instead of `\d` in my original Regex.

Comment: tried with the string **(?<=^|\\s)\\d{1,3}(?: \\d{3})*(?:,\\d{1,3})?(?=\\s|$)** but still doesn't work. any ideas ? thx very much for all your help and support.

Comment: @RaduPuspana sorry I have no idea. I would try to test it step by step what is the unescaped character. At first try to match for only `\d`, then try `\d{3}` and so add more and more characters till you found the one you probably need to escape.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5225/discussion-between-radu-puspana-and-stema)

Comment: thx so so much for all the support. much much appreciated. shall try to do as you said. and let you know. thx so very much

Comment: I have just discovered that VBA doesn't agree with this sequence of the regex ?<=^

Any ideas ? Thx for all the support and your TIME !

Comment: @RaduPuspana `(?<=^|\s)` is a lookbehind, if this is not supported replace it with `(?:^|\s)`, but then the whitespace is also matched, if you don't want it, you need to remove it then afterwards.

Comment: Thx so much for the help. What do you mean by 1. "the whitespace is also matched" ? in regexr I have inserted the new expression and entered a space character and it didn't match it. 2. "remove it then afterwards" ? How would I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading on a line by line basis, you might consider adding anchors (`^` and `$`) to your regex, so you will end up with something like so:

```
^(\d{1,3}\s(\d{3}\s)*\d{3}(\,\d{1,3})?|\d{1,3}\,\d{1,3})$
```

This instructs the RegEx engine to start matching from the beginning of the line till the very end.

Comment: on my case it doesn't work. I shall give more detail in a minute. thx for your time and support